# Fast way to apply custom function to every pixel in image

Tags: python, image, numpy

I'm looking for a faster way to apply a custom function to an image which I use to remove a blue background. I have a function that calculates the distance each pixel is from approximately the blue colour in the background. The original code with a loop looked like this:

```
def dist_to_blue(pix):
    rdist = 76 - pix[0]
    gdist = 150 - pix[1]
    bdist = 240 - pix[2]
    return rdist*rdist + gdist*gdist + bdist*bdist

imgage.shape #outputs (576, 720, 3)
for i, row in enumerate(image):
    for j, pix in enumerate(row):
        if dist_to_blue(pix) < 12000: image[i,j] = [255,255,255]
```

However this code takes around 8 seconds to run for this relatively small image. I've been trying to use numpy's "vectorize" function but that applies the function to every value individually. However I want to do it to every pixel aka not expand the z/rgb dimension

the only improvements I've come up with is replacing the for loops with the following:

`m = np.apply_along_axis(lambda pix: (255,255,255) if dist_to_blue(pix) < 12000 else pix, 2, image)`

Which runs in about 7 seconds which is still painfully slow. Is there something I'm missing that could speed this up to a reasonable execution time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach incorporating the answers of @dash-tom-bang and @kevinkayaks

```
# Assume the image is of shape (h, w, 3)
# Precompute some data
RDIST = np.array([(76 - r)**2 for r in range(256)])
GDIST = np.array([(150 - g)**2 for g in range(256)])
BDIST = np.array([(240 - b)**2 for b in range(256)])

# Calculate and apply mask
mask = (RDIST[image[:,:,0]] + GDIST[image[:,:,1]] + BDIST[image[:,:,2]]) < 12000
image[mask] = [255,255,255]
```

Comment: I like the idea but as is I don't think this works as is. You need to develop the difference array and then use these precomputed values to develop a matrix of squared differences. I'd like to see it ! It will work and it will be faster

Comment: @kevinkayaks, yes there was slight mixing of dimension, I had earlier assumed (3, h, w). Corrected.

Comment: This still doesn't work. You're assuming lists support fancy indexing

Comment: After converting the precomputed values to a numpy array it works like a charm: `RDIST = np.array([(76 - r)**2 for r in range(256)])`

Answer (score 2):

This should be a lil bit faster ... ;)

```
import numpy as np 
blue = np.full_like(image, [76,150,250])
mask = np.sum((image-blue)**2,axis=-1) < 12000
image[mask] = [255,0,255]
```

Here you're generating the ideal blue image, squaring the difference of the images pixel by pixel, then summing over the last axis (the rgb vectors) before generating a mask and using it to modify values in the original image.

Comment: Perfect! this reduces the running time to 0.01 seconds! However to get it working I had to avoid overflowing of the 8bit uint when squaring the difference by changing it to a 16 or 32 bit uint:  `mask = np.sum((image-blue)**2,axis=-1, dtype=np.uint16) < 12000`

Comment: instead of `blue = np.full_like(image, [76,150,250])` you can just do `blue = np.array([76,150,250])` and let broadcasting do the rest.  And since you're not uisng a `*_like` operator (which makes `blue.dtype == image.dtype == 'uint8'`) you wan't have to specify `uint16` later as it will already be a standard `uint32`

Answer (score 2):

This is just a shot in the dark but maybe precomputing some data would help? I don't know for sure but the table lookup may be faster than the add and multiply?

```
def square(x): # maybe there's a library function for this?
    return x*x

RDIST = [square(76 - r) for r in range(256)]
GDIST = [square(150 - g) for g in range(256)]
BDIST = [square(240 - b) for b in range(256)]

def dist_to_blue(pix):
    return RDIST[pix[0]] + GDIST[pix[1]] + BDIST[pix[2]]
```

I suspect too if you have a way to just get an array of pixels per row that might be faster, instead of indexing each individual pixel, but I don't know the libraries in play.

Answer (score 2):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

blue = np.array([76, 150, 250])

def crush_color(image, color, thr = np.sqrt(12000), new = np.array([255, 255, 255]));
    dist_to_color = cdist(image.reshape(-1, 3), color, 'sqeuclidean').reshape(image.shape[:-1])
    image[dist_to_color[..., None] < thr**2] = new

crush_color(image, blue)
```

1) instead of doing distance manually, use `cdist` which will calculate the distances (squared ueclidean in this case) much faster even than `numpy` broadcasting.

2) Do the replacement in place

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to accelerate your Numpy code by getting ride of `for loops`, like using Numpy's ufuncs (`+`, `-`, `*`, `**`, `<`...), aggregations (`sum`, `max`, `min`, `mean`...), broadcasting, masking, fancy indexing.
The code below may give you some tips:

```
dist = np.expand_dims(np.array([76, 150, 240]), axis=0)
image[np.where(np.sum((image-dist)**2, axis=2) < 12000)]=255
```

Comment: `np.where` isn't necessary, but is it faster ? I like the use of expand dims. That is cool.