# Fastest way to apply a function to each pixel of image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Started learning python less than a week ago. Maybe my question is really n00b'ish one, but I spent about six hours today trying to find an answer, but failed.

I have found multiple solutions of applying functions to each point in CHANNEL in image (R, G and B) separately, but I need to analyze each pixel on all three channels simultaneously.
So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997022/fast-way-to-apply-custom-function-to-every-pixel-in-image) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863967/pil-apply-the-same-operation-to-every-pixel) don't fit, or I severely don't understand something.

What I have is an RGB .png image (actually, it's a screenshot made with MSS , so maybe it's faster to work with it directly than save/load? but I don't know exactly **how** to do that... *yet*).
The image consists of colored pixels and gray pixels of different brightness.

I need to filter this image into "mode 1" image, in which every pixel is set to **0** (solid|black) or **1** (blank|white) according to following rule: if source pixel (*all pixels are [R,G,B]*) is colored (R != G or G != B or B != R), the resulting pixel is **1** (blank|white), OR if it's not colored but brighter than #eee , it's **1** (blank|white). Only if source pixel not colored (R == G == B) AND it's darker than #eee, resulting pixel is **0** (solid|black).

Just changing mode / filtering by threshold won't work, since colored pixels can be quite dark. Darker than gray ones, actually.

Maybe there is some library/function that already does what I need, but I quite un-epically failed to find one.

So it's a function like:

```
#accepts [R,G,B] or (R,G,B)
def process_pixel(pixel) :
  if (1 == len(set(pixel)) and (238 > pixel[0]) :
    return 0
  else 
    return 1
```

Now I need to apply this function (well, maybe some OTHER, much better function, which I just can't image with my severely limited python knowledge -- yet) to every pixel of image and with this create a new image.

Today I've read about pillow/PIL library and decided to use it (I've also read about openCV library, but that's some kind of monster for handleing *computer vision*, which kinda shivers me timbers... **a lot**)
The script looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image

in_image = Image.open('guineapig.png')

in_pixels = in_image.getdata()

out_pixels = []
for pixel in in_pixels :
  out_pixels.append(process_pixel(pixel))

out_image = Image.new('1', (*in_image.size, ), (1))
out_image.putdata(out_pixels)
out_image.save('guineapig_1.png')
```

Now this works but it's kinda slow. To say the least.
Since I'm using python less than a week and this is my fourth script, ever, I don't even understand which part slows it down most and what to do with it...

Comment: Do you have any sample of input images and output(expected) image?

Comment: Also to double check, a pixel in output image is blank (white) if the input image is colourful (e.g. has 3 RGB channels) "OR" it is a grayscale image but brighter than 238? Because I feel a mismatch between what you mentioned and your `process_pixel` funciton

Comment: example image? yes, I do.
http://darquan.ru/_/krolik.png

Not **WHOLE IMAGE* needs to be blank, no.
This is about each *pixel* separately. a pixel needs to be blank (white) if it's colored (the channels R, G, B hold different values for that exact pixel) or if it's brighter that #eee.

Comment: also edited my question to be more clear than I meant.

Comment: Ow. That approach I missed. Actually, should be **0** (black) if saturation=0 AND brightness < 92% and **1** (white) otherwise. And yes, if I can access brightness and saturation channels with pillow/PIL library, that'll do the trick. The question remains, how. Recode image to 'HSV' mode, then process each channel, then do... exactly what? I'll need to apply some kind of "AND" process to each resulting image (I'll get one from each channel, right?). But how do I do that? Kinda escapes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you just need to process the saturation and brightness channel of the HSV version of the input image so that your latter condition is satisfied setting the dark gray shade pixels to 0 (i.e., those with saturation=0 and brightness<238) and making the remaining pixels 1. This can be done using OpenCV (or Python Wand) rather easily.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# if source pixel not colored (R == G == B) i.e. saturation=0 
# and it's darker than #eee i.e. brightness<238, 
# then resulting pixel is 0 (solid|black); 
# else 1 (solid|white)

# load image and get dimensions
img = cv2.imread("krolik.png")

# convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# separate out saturation and brightness channels
sat = hsv[:,:,1]
bri = hsv[:,:,2]

# saturation=0 indicates not colored pixels and saturation>0 indicates colored pixels
# do inverse threshold saturation image at 0 
# result is colored pixels will become 0 and those not-colored will become 1
sat_thresh = cv2.threshold(sat,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1].astype("float32")/255

# inverse threshold brightness image at 238 (#eee)
# so pixels with brightness > 238 will become 0 and those less than 238 will become 1
bri_thresh = cv2.threshold(bri,238,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1].astype("float32")/255

# multiply above two images to get dark not colored pixels as 1
dark_not_colored = sat_thresh*bri_thresh

# invert that result so that dark not colored pixels are 0 and others are 1
result = 1-dark_not_colored

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("krolik_processed.png", 255*result.astype("uint8"))

# display it
cv2.imshow("sat_thresh", sat_thresh)
cv2.imshow("bri_thresh", bri_thresh)
cv2.imshow("dark_not_colored", dark_not_colored)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

ADDITION:

Here is how it would be done in Imagemagick (unix syntax), which comes with most Linux systems and is also available for Mac OSX and Windows.

```
convert krolik.png \
-colorspace HSV \
-separate -delete 0 \
\( -clone 0 -threshold 0 -negate \) \
\( -clone 1 -threshold 93.33% -negate \) \
-delete 0,1 \
-compose multiply -composite \
-negate \
krolick_processed_im.png
```

Comment: Wow, that's WAY faster than what I came up with, I think because of using built-in pre-compiled functions, not iterating lists (which is what usually slowing down scripts in python as far as I understand). Thank you really much!

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to look at Python Wand also. It may be easier for you to program and has lots of functions that make things easy, since it is based upon Imagemagick. You do have to install Imagemagick, though. Note my addition in my answer where I show the code equivalent in Imagemagick (one command line split into multiple lines for easy reading).

Comment: I'm familiar with ImageMagick from my days as freelance php developer, so maybe it'll be simplier for me to use it. But, I'm learning Python right now, and this script I started to better understand how Python works. So from that position, it's better to do it python way. Thanks for advise about Python Wand anyway!

Comment: Thanks to you I already learned how to directly process the screenshot without creating temporary file AND process it into "mode 1" AND run tesseract recognition on it in one go, which was what I was trying to do from the start (tesseract didn't want to recognise image good enough while it had those colored 'bonus' makrs for letters). I was wrong to be afraid of  OpenCV library, thank you again!